# How to make borders thicker in Libreoffice?

Tags: libreoffice

I have a passage with a border-bottom line. I've added this line from the `insert > Horizontal line` option.

How could I make this line thicker in a value-controlled way?

I don't have such an option here:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually the "Width" option there.

I would call it "Height" because it's the height of the line but I guess anyone could philosophize on this a bit...